# Log-sum-exp is the conjugate of relative entropy: a quick proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, entropy, legendre-transformation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, dm)$ be a measure space. For measurable functions $f\colon \Omega\to \mathbb R$ such that $\exp(f)$ is integrable, and for $\rho>0$ such that $\int \rho\, dm=1$, we define
$$
L(f)=\log\int_\Omega e^{f}\, dm,\quad \text{and}\  \quad H(\rho)=\int_{\Omega} \rho\log\rho\, dm. $$
These two functionals satisfy the Legendre-Fenchel inequality
$$\tag{1}
\int_\Omega f\rho\, dm\le L(f)+H(\rho), $$
with equality if $e^f=C\rho$ for some $C>0$.

**Question**. Is there a direct proof of (1) based on the Jensen inequality? [In the first page of this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00534442/document), J.Lehec suggest that this is "easily seen" to be the case.

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605026/8157) seems to be strictly related, and it does contain a proof of (1). However, I wonder if there is a "one-line" proof of (1), one that does not need to introduce a lot of definitions.

---

I can prove (1) by means of the variational calculus. Namely, I can prove that
$$\tag{2}
H(\rho)=\max_{\exp(f)\in L^1} \left( \int_{\Omega} f\rho\, dm - L(f)\right).$$
(This is essentially the same computation that I find, for example, [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2614316/8157), concerning the finite-dimensional case).

For a bounded $g$, we let $f=f_\star+\epsilon g$ in the term in brackets in (2), noting that $\exp(f_\star +\epsilon g)\in L^1$ if $\exp(f_\star)\in L^1$ (that is, $g$ is an admissible variation). We differentiate in $\epsilon$, then set $\epsilon=0$, inferring that $f_\star$ is a critical point if and only if
$$
\int_\Omega g\rho\, dm = \frac{\int_\Omega e^{f_\star} g\,dm}{\int_\Omega e^{f_\star}\, dm}, \quad \forall g\in L^\infty(\Omega).$$
We immediately see that $f_\star=\log \rho$ is a critical point (not unique), and since $L$ is convex, the functional to maximize in (2) is concave, hence all critical points are maximizers.$^{[1]}$ Thus, plugging $f=f_\star$ in (2) we conclude the proof.

---

[1] This might need to restrict the domain of $L$, since $\{f\,:\,\exp(f)\in L^1\}$ is not a vector space. **EDIT**: As Olivier Diaz points out in the comments, this domain is a convex set. This is a consequence of the Hölder inequality. Therefore, it is true that critical points are maximizers, as stated above.

Comment: The proper domain is not a linear space but it is convex set. Outside the functional $L$ can be set to $\infty$. I believe then the rest is just the Frenchel-Legendre theorem.

Comment: I guess $f$ is defined on $\Omega$ rather than on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I incorporated both comments into the question, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\rho \, \mathrm{d}m$ defines a probability measure on $\Omega$. So by the Jensen's inequality,

$$ \exp\left(\int_{\Omega} (f - \log\rho) \, \rho \, \mathrm{d}m \right)
\leq \int_{\Omega} \exp(f - \log\rho) \, \rho \, \mathrm{d}m
= \int_{\Omega} e^{f} \, \mathrm{d}m. $$

This is equivalent to the inequality in question.

Moreover, since $\exp(\cdot)$ is strictly convex, the equality holds precisely when $f - \log\rho$ is constant a.s. with respect to $\rho \, \mathrm{d}m$, which is equivalent to $e^f = C\rho$ a.e. with respect to $m$ for some constant $C > 0$.

Comment: Very neat, thanks a lot!